# Get all attributes implemented by type of generic list

Tags: c#

I have the following product class

```
[MyCustomAttribute ]
public class Product   {

}
```

And the following list of products

```
var list = new List<Product>();
```

I want the `MyCustomAttribute` from the `List`.

I am currently trying:

```
 var attributes = (MyCustomAttribute[]) list
   .GetType()
   .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyCustomAttribute ));
```

But this seem to not return anything...

Comment: that would be GetType

Comment: Do you really inherit `Product` class from *attribute* `MyCustomAttribute`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko no, this is just an exampling trying to illustrate my issue.

Comment: your question is very unclear right now

Comment: Isn't there a way to find that list is for a product type and then find the attribute on the product?

Comment: my bad sorry the : MyCustomAttribute is on the product. I have updated my question

Answer (score 3):

`List<T>` hasn't been attributed with `MyCustomAttribute` but list's *items* have:

```
   [MyCustomAttribute(...)]
   public class Product {...}

   var list = new List<Product>();

   ...

   MyCustomAttribute[] attributes = list
     .Where(item => item != null)
     .SelectMany(item => item.GetType().GetCustomAttributes<MyCustomAttribute>())
     .ToArray();
```

Comment: However, there is zero point in returning a list of attributes when they're all the same thing.

Comment: @DavidG: imagine that we have derived `Product2`, `Product3` etc classes with their own attributes (which can be deriived from `MyCustomAttribute`)

Comment: Yes, and what would anyone expect to do with that list after they'd been disassociated with the product they're attributed to?

Comment: @DavidG: Pure invention: do we have (in the entire list) any `Product` attributed with `MyCustomObsoleteAttribute`? (there's a better solution for sure)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert a list of devired class to list of base class, you can do like this

```
var attributes = list.Select(x=> (MyCustomAttribute)x);
```

or

```
var attributes = list.ConvertAll(x => (MyCustomAttribute)x);
```

or

```
var attributes = list.Cast<MyCustomAttribute>();
```

Comment: can't do that I have to work it out based on the list type

Comment: What do you mean John? What do you have to work out?